# Compare 2 JDBC responses (SQL) in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to compare 2 JDBC responses (SQL):

I have responses from JDBC request as below in table format:

(Source DB)JDBC Response 1:

City    Population
A       100
B       151

(Target DB)JDBC Response 2:

City    Population
A       110
B       152

I am saving the response as String in JDBC Request (in Result Variable Name)

Now how do I compare the values in each column and Print Pass when values match. Fail it when the values do not match.

Number of rows can change.

Need help with assertion code or any other way this can be achieved in Jmeter.

I want to compare population of each city between source and target and decide whether matched or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just go for [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

1. Add Response Assertion as a child of the 2nd JDBC Request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable to Use: `response1`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to Test: `${response2}`

     [image]

That's in, in case of mismatch the `JDBC Request 2` will be marked as failed and you will be able to see the differences using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or in .jtl results file

[image]

More information: [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/)

Comment: thank you sir for such a quick and apt reply..!. If I have huge volume of data  in a table that need to be compared, lets say some 100K records between source and destination, do you have any thoughts how to do this in a better way and capture those mismatched records only. I'm sorry if my question is dumb, I'm new to Jmeter.